# Is there a way to resize masonic columns when sidebar close?

Tags: reactjs, masonry

I am trying to implement a masonry style layout in my reactjs website the package that i am currently using is [masonic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/masonic?activeTab=readme) , Out of the other packages that I have tried it works the best so far but I am having a issue with resizing of the columns when I open and then reclose the sidebar.

When I first open the sidebar the columns resize fine to fit into the container but when I reclose the sidebar the columns does not resize to fit in the container.

[image: how it currently looks]

The example above shows the columns resizing correctly when sidebar opens but not when it close.

Copy of code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Masonry, } from 'masonic';
import { useWindowSize } from '@react-hook/window-size';
import '../MasonryGridLayout.css';


export const GrideView = () => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false)
  const [refHeight, setheight] = useState(null)
  const [sideBar, setSideBar] = useState(false)
  const [windowWidth, height] = useWindowSize()

  const handleSidebar = () => {
    setSideBar(!sideBar)
    if (ref.current) {
      console.log('current')
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMobile = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 720) {
        setIsMobile(true)
      } else {
        setIsMobile(false)
      }
    }
    handleMobile()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div style={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column'
    }}>
      <div className='header-style'>
        <button style={{
          width: 'auto',
          height: '20px',
          backgroundColor: 'teal',
          color: 'white',
          marginLeft: '20px',
         
        }}
          onClick={handleSidebar}
        >
          toggle Sidebar
        </button>
        <button style={{
          width: 'auto',
          height: '20px',
          backgroundColor: 'tan',
          color: 'white',
          marginLeft: '20px',
         
        }}
        >
          Upload
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="wrapper">
        {
          isMobile ? null : sideBar ? <div className='side-bar-style'>
            this is a side bar
          </div> : null
        }
        <div className='masonic' style={{ height: `${refHeight}` }}>
          <Masonry
            // Provides the data for our grid items
            items={items}
            // Adds 8px of space between the grid cells
            columnGutter={8}
            maxColumnCount={sideBar ? 7 : 8}
            columnCount={windowWidth < 600 && 2}
            // Sets the minimum column width to 172px
            columnWidth={172}
            // Pre-renders 5 windows worth of content
            overscanBy={2}
            // This is the grid item component
            render={FakeCard}
          />
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


const FakeCard = ({ data: { postID, post, description } }) => (
  <div className='card-style' style={{ height: `${description}` }}>
    <img
      className='img-style'
      alt="kitty"
      src={post}
    />
  </div>
);
```

How can I get the column to resize correctly when the sidebar close ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the useResizeObserver() hook.

> This hook creates a resize observer that forces updates to the grid
> cell positions when mutations are made to cells affecting their
> height.